# Listing files in Google Cloud bucket with thousands of files.

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm running a Node.js script to get the number of files in a bucket on Google Cloud Storage.

In a bucket with about 30K files, I get a result in a few seconds. In a bucket with about 300K files, I get the following error:

```js
<--- Last few GCs --->

[10508:0000014DB738ADB0]  2053931 ms: Mark-sweep 1400.6 (1467.7) -> 1400.6 (1437.2) MB, 1292.2 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 1292 ms) last resort GC in old space requested
[10508:0000014DB738ADB0]  2055233 ms: Mark-sweep 1400.6 (1437.2) -> 1400.6 (1437.2) MB, 1301.9 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000001A6B8025EE1 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [D:\Libraries\Documents\project-name\node_modules\@google-cloud\storage\src\acl.js:~717] [pc=0000005E62D95DCF](this=0000016DB7602311 <undefined>,accessMethod=0000016DB7602AC1 <String[3]: add>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 3->1
    3: forEach(this=00000335A20E8891 <JSArray[2]>)
    4: /* anonymous */(a...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Below is the code I'm using. Is there a better way?

```js
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

function listFiles(bucketName) {
  // [START storage_list_files]
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library


  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following line before running the sample.
   */
  // const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';

  // Lists files in the bucket
  return storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .getFiles(); ///const files = results[0];
  // [END storage_list_files]
}

listFiles('bucket-name')
    .then(x => {
        console.log('Number of files: ', x[0].length)
    });
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are running out of memory to store the returned results. You will need to use the APIs and page the output. This will limit the number of items returned for each response.

Comment: How would I use the API to get a list of files? Can you link to the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the methods that return lists offer a streaming version of said method. In this case you'll want to use [`bucket.getFilesStream()`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/src/bucket.ts#L911)

```
bucket.getFilesStream()
  .on('error', console.error)
  .on('data', function(file) {
    // file is a File object.
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    // All files retrieved.
  });
```

Alternatively you can disable auto pagination and manual page through the results

```
const callback = function(err, files, nextQuery, apiResponse) {
  if (nextQuery) {
    // More results exist.
    bucket.getFiles(nextQuery, callback);
  }
};

bucket.getFiles({
  autoPaginate: false
}, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments you should use the [`Objects: list`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) API to list large buckets.

Also, if I am reading the [library documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/Bucket#getFiles) correctly you can set the `autoPaginate` option to `false` and manually iterate over the results, without having to talk to the JSON api directly.